# I can’t install snapd in CentOS

Tags: centos, snap

Hope someone can help me. I have tried to install snapd on CentOS Linux 7.9.2009 following these instructions: [LINK](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-centos) .

It seems to install perfectly via “yum install snapd”, but wanting to run the following command, this is what I get:

> systemctl enable --now snapd.socket Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

I am root user. Anyway, I tried using sudo and got the same message. What I can do?